# Replace specific column with values passed as parameter in a file within loop in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Suppose we have a file `test_file.csv`:

```
"261718"|"2017-08-21"|"ramesh_1"|"111"
"261719"|"2017-08-23"|"suresh_1"|"112"
```

required modified  test_file.csv should be :

```
"261718"|"2017-08-21"|"ramesh"|"111"
"261719"|"2017-08-23"|"suresh"|"112"
```

How would I find and replace the third column with the required values passed as parameters? It should be within an iteration.

Comment: Do you want same for 6th column also?

Comment: @Utsav That was just a formatting problem.

Comment: for 3rd column specifically, i need to replaced the values in file. e.g.  ramesh_1 to ramesh  , suresh_1 to suresh , booking_done to booking & so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can save your arguments as comma separated values and store it in a variable args.

Pass this variable to `awk` using `-v` option. overwrite the third column `$3`  with nth array element where n is the current row number

```
args='"ramesh","suresh"'

awk  -F "|" -v args=$args '
BEGIN { 
       split(args,arr,",") 
      }
{
   $3=arr[NR];OFS=FS;print

}' test_file.csv
```

Output:

```
"261718"|"2017-08-21"|"ramesh"|"111"                                                                                                                                     
"261719"|"2017-08-23"|"suresh"|"112"
```